# pkg-config file openmp dependency

Tags: pkg-config

I want to write a pkg-config for a library that uses openmp internally.

My .pc file reads

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=/usr/local
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: LightFEM
Description: 
Version: 1.0.0

Requires: openmp
Libs: -L${libdir} -lLightFEM
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

However pkg-config returns the following error

```
Package openmp was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `openmp.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'openmp', required by 'LightFEM', not found
```

How sould I write my .pc file ?